# Dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest

I read all other posts here that are related to this error. Maybe I am missing something here but I don't know what. I am using textArea to input text in it (html text).
This text area is bounded to my domain class property

```
public class SomeClass{
...
[AllowHtml]       
        public string CommentText { get; set; }
...
}
```

I have also tried to add **[ValidateInput(false)]** attribute but nothing. But by reading error text I see that request doesn't even come to controller it is broken in **Application_BeginRequest()**.
This is error message:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (CommentText="<p>ddd</p>")
Line 23:         protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 24:         {
Line 25:             if (HttpContext.Current.Request["RequireUploadifySessionSync"] != null)
Line 26:                 UploadifySessionSync();
Line 27:         }

Source File: D:\Projects\...\Global.asax.cs    Line: 25 

Stack Trace: 


[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (CommentText="<p>ddd</p>").]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +8755668
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +122
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +114
```

I know that I can turn off check ok whole application in web config. But I need this only in one case (to allow HTML input).
More strange is that this works a few days ago and I didn't change anything here, just login and logout users.
What am I doing wrong here?
Ok now I remove this code fom global.asax:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["RequireUploadifySessionSync"] != null)
                UploadifySessionSync();
```

And now it works. But I need this code here. Why is it produce this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been answered.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/3368769#3368769)

You need to change the way your handling request validations to revert it back to 2.0

Comment: Hah I read only first two answers. But why it has to be reverted?

Answer (score 0):

Your specific issue is that you've got code looking at the request parameters in BeginRequest which is earlier in the ASP.NET pipeline than when your models are bound (where an `AllowHtml` or `ValidateInput` attribute would come into play).

It looks like you are enforcing security around a flash upload with your code (I am doing something *very* similar.

In my case I ended up just catching an `HttpRequestValidationException` in the BeginRequest method and swallowing the exception.  It is not best practice, but the validation will be performed later in the pipeline so you still have control over the validation.